# Show that the improper integral $\int_1^\infty f(x) \ dx$ exists iff $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, improper-integrals

The assignment:

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers and $f: [1, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, defined by $f(x) = a_n$, for $x \in [n,n+1).$ Show that: 
>   $$\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_1^b f(x) \ dx  $$ exists if and only if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$converges. Similarly show that the equivalence also holds for the absolute improper integral and that if we have convergence the equality  $\int_1^\infty f(x) \ dx   = \sum_1^\infty a_n$ is true.

I think the comparison tests for both series and integrals might be helpful but I don't know which inequality to use to get from the series to the integral and vice versa, since I need either two integrals or two series to use a comparison test.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Proof.

Comment: There shouldn't be a $\lim_{b\to\infty}$ in the first integral.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar f is neither necessarily non-negative nor decreasing.

Comment: Doesn't $f$ needs to be monotone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\displaystyle \int _1^\infty f=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\int _{n}^{n+1}f\right)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(a_n\right)$.

Comment: I like that hint, might just be what I was looking for. I'll try it.

Comment: @KitKat Was it enough?

Comment: Since the assignment shows a strong resemblance with the integral test for convergence, I tried to approach it similarly, but because $f$ is neither non-negative nor decreasing, I can't get the correct estimates (even with your hint).

Comment: @KitKat I added something trivial, but perhaps you missed it. Does it help?

Comment: You say it's trivial, but I'll have to ask anyway. How is the infinite sum of infinite partitioned integrals equal to the series of function values? Edit: That is basically a part of the assignment.

Comment: @KitKat Simply because $$\displaystyle \int _{n}^{n+1}f(x)\mathrm dx=\int _n^{n+1}f_{\mid [n, n+1[}(x)\mathrm dx=\int _n^{n+1}a_n\mathrm dx=a_n(n+1-n).$$ And please don't take my comment the wrong way. I said it because it's obvious you can handle this, you just happened to miss it. It happens to every one.

Comment: @KitKat Feel free to ask me any follow up questions you want.

Comment: Ah, it really is simple. Though, doesn't the equality already prove the assertion? If the improper integral exists in $\mathbb{R}$, the equality automatically implies that the convergence of the series holds true (and vice versa), right? Maybe I'm missing something, but if that is sufficient to prove it, the second part, in which we observe the absolute values on both sides, automatically follows as well.

Comment: @KitKat You're correct and indeed with the absolute value it is the same thing. But there is one subtlety here. If they converge, then you have an equality of real numbers and every thing is fine. But if they diverge, you're actually saying $\infty =\infty$ and this might be something devoided of meaning. It is OK, though, you just need to recall than an integral is a limit and so is a series, so in case of divergence you're simply saying the limits are equal and that is perfectly rigorous. But, as I said, what you said in your previous comment is enough.

Comment: Yes, I'll have to rephrase that a little bit. Thanks a lot for your help. I regularly ask questions and I always appreciate it if someone takes his time helping and discussing a simple problem like that because it often deepens my understanding more than just a plain solution.

Comment: @KitKat You're welcome.